# How to enable antialiasing for SVG Images?

Tags: unity

My game has vector icons and sprites, like this one:

[image]

Its quality disappoints me. I guess that antialiasing is disabled here for some reason, but have no idea how to turn it on.

The problem is only with UI component **SVG Image**. **Sprite Renderer** seems to not have this issue:

[image]

Regular **Image** does not support vector icons. I tried this approach.

MSAA is enabled on **Camera** and in **Quality** settings. When it's disabled, second sprite becomes exactly the same as first.

---

Unity version: 2018.2.7.f1 for Linux
Vector graphics package version: 1.0.0-preview.23

---

I will accept a solution or an optimal workaround of any complexity. But please don't suggest using raster images.

Why?

- I have to compress them because the game is for WebGL and I already had problems with memory because of textures. Vector sprites take less memory.
- Without mipmaps icons are pixelated. With mipmaps, they look blurry. They are all power of two, but at different scales. They are even blurred different, some more, some less. I can't use fixed-sized sprites because there's an animation that changes zoom, and canvas will rescale in fullscreen.

Vector guns are to the left, raster ones with mipmaps - to the right. Thin black border lines are gone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why rasters are unsuitable for your needs here? They're somewhat of an industry standard for small icon graphics like this, so if you have a particular need to not use them, it sounds like a relevant detail to expand upon in your question.

Comment: @DMGregory question edited.

Comment: The blurring artifacts you're showing usually come from a mismatch between the native resolution of the asset and the size you're drawing it on-screen. If you have a standard size you're drawing these icons, you can eliminate aliasing and blurring by exporting the raster asset at exactly that pixel size. If you don't down-scale it, then you don't need mipmaps for UI sprites.

Comment: @DMGregory they have animation on mouse hovering which alters zoom. I can't avoid blurring. They're also scaled for different screen resolutions.

Comment: Then *that's* the constraint you should describe in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antialiasing in overlay canvas is [broken and won't be fixed](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ui-components-eg-image-component-is-no-longer-anti-aliasing-in-game-view-with-screen-space-overlay-canvas). However, there's a workaround that worked for me:

### Set the canvas Render Mode to Screen Space - Camera, and then set its Render Camera to your main camera.

Antialiasing will work. It breaks some features, spotlight masks for example, but it's okay because I don't use them. More info in [this thread on Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-ui-svg-support-script.551254/).

If you have a separate canvas for background, you will need to change it too, because overlay canvases are rendered over other canvases.